# Картинка на весь экран в bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Как сделать картинку на весь экран как вот тут http://gridelicious.net/themes/treble/demo/

Answer (score 3):

Бутстрап тут особо ни при чём. В том числе и в данном примере. А делается такое просто: блок растягивается по ширине и высоте экрана

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

а затем ему даётся

```
background:url(нужная_картинка.jpeg) center no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
```

Comment: это в css прописывать?

Comment: да, css, как ни странно, прописывается в css :)

Судя по всему не лишним будет ещё один нюанс упомянуть: Для того, чтобы высота 100% сработала, нужно для html, body тоже указать высоту 100%

Собственно, вот работающий пример: http://jsfiddle.net/Jz9y9/

Comment: Чеши-ка ты, Никита, css учить.

Comment: не получается картинка вообще не появляется
что писать в html и что писать в css? можешь помочь новичку...